# Recursive path finding in matrix

Tags: c, recursion, matrix, tail-recursion

I need to find a path of the number `1` in a `matrix[R][C]` starting from `matrix[0][0]` until it gets to `matrix[R-1][C-1]`, using recursion. I can only go down or right.
In most cases, I don't have a problem. My problem is only when there is nowhere to go, and I need to take a step backwards.

Per example, this is the matrix I'm getting from a file:

```
1 0 0 0 0 0
1 1 0 0 0 0
1 1 0 0 0 0
1 1 1 1 0 1
1 0 1 1 1 1
0 1 0 1 1 1
```

The problem is when it gets to `matrix[4][0]`. I don't understand why it won't go back in the recursion. It returns false when it should return true.

This is the code:

```
int findPath(int matrix[][C],int rowSize,int colSize)
{
    int a=0,b=0;
    if(Find_Path(matrix,rowSize,colSize,a,b)==0)
    {
        printf("The function return - False\n");
        return 0;
    }
    else 
    {
        printf("The function return - True\n");
        return 1;
    }
} 

int Find_Path(int matrix[][C],int rowSize,int colSize,int a,int b)
{
    if(a==(rowSize-1) && (b==colSize-1))
        return 1;
    if(matrix[a+1][b]==1)
        return Find_Path(matrix,rowSize-1,colSize-1,a+1,b);
    if(matrix[a][b+1]==1)
        return Find_Path(matrix,rowSize-1,colSize-1,a,b+1);

    if(matrix[a+1][b]==0 && matrix[a][b+1]==0)
        return 0;
}
```

Comment: did you debug to see what's going wrong?

Comment: You show a 6x6 matrix so it should be possible to proceed beyond matrix[4][0].  Index 5 should be the limit in each direction.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- Your recursion function is wrong in that it only tries first '1'
  neighbor cell it sees.
- The recursion erroneously takes a look only to smaller part of the matrix. You have either to adapt the matrix size (but then also its origin), or coordinates. Not both.
- The fail condition (the last if) is wrong and bogus.

```
    int Find_Path(int matrix[][C],int rowSize,int colSize,int a,int b)
    {
       if(a==(rowSize-1) && (b==colSize-1))
          return 1;
       if(matrix[a+1][b]==1  &&  Find_Path(matrix,rowSize,colSize,a+1,b))
          return 1;
       if(matrix[a][b+1]==1  &&  Find_Path(matrix,rowSize,colSize,a,b+1))
          return 1;
       return 0;
    }
```

(I have not tested it though.)

Comment: hi dear thanx but yours will retuen true when is't not. for example this matrix: (1 0 0 0 0 0; 
              1 0 0 0 0 0;
              0 0 0 0 0 0;
              1 1 1 1 0 1;
              1 0 1 1 1 1;
              0 0 0 1 1 1)

Comment: I only addressed one bug I saw in your code at the 1st sight. Yes I can now see yet another one (and edited the answer), but still there may be more.

Comment: you made me to debug it for you :( Now it seems to work (at least for few matrices I tried).

Comment: If this is a _compulsory_ requirement to make it recursive (for academic purpose I guess) then, it's ok.
But if you consider more global pathfinding problems, you should turn on iterative implementations (or you'll get a ... Stack Overflow -well, easy play-on-word, sorry for that one-). You could study Dijkstra Algorithm for example.

Answer (score 1):

You need to check you're not dropping off the matrix, and I find it slightly neater to check the 1's and 0's in the matrix after rather than before the move. Putting those together gives this code.

```
int find_path(int matrix[R][C], int i, int j) {
    if (!matrix[i][j]) return 0;
    if (i == R-1 && j == C-1) return 1;
    return i+1<R && find_path(matrix, i+1, j) ||
           j+1<C && find_path(matrix, i, j+1));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

At `[3][0]`, `if(matrix[a+1][b]==1)` will get succeeded and it will try to call `return Find_Path(matrix,rowSize-1,colSize-1,4,0);` Now the return value is 0, then you are returning directly. Return `1` from that place only if that recursive call returns `1`.

```
if(matrix[a+1][b]==1)
    if(Find_Path(matrix,rowSize-1,colSize-1,a+1,b)) return 1;
if(matrix[a][b+1]==1)
    if(Find_Path(matrix,rowSize-1,colSize-1,a,b+1)) return 1;
```

Becuase in your code call for `[4][0]` its returning `0` and you are returning from that place itself with `0`. You are not going for the next check `if(matrix[a][b+1]==1)`

Comment: hi dear thanx but yours will retuen true when is't not. for example this matrix: (1 0 0 0 0 0; 
              1 0 0 0 0 0;
              0 0 0 0 0 0;
              1 1 1 1 0 1;
              1 0 1 1 1 1;
              0 0 0 1 1 1)

Comment: 3rd row is full of zeros, `if(matrix[a+1][b]==0 && matrix[a][b+1]==0)` condition will get succeed and it returns zero right.