# Find a path between two cordinates in a matrix

Tags: algorithm

So, i have this problem.
I have this matrix :

```
1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1
1 1 0 0 0 1 0 T 0 1
H 0 0 1 1 1 0 1 1 1
1 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1
1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1
```

I need to build a path that starts from the H which has coordinates (3.1) to T(2.8)
I need:
I need a program that reads a matrix A[1..M,1..N] which itself represents a labyrinth with elements [0,1] and also reads the H,T value. The value 1 is conisdered as a wall, you can't pass through it.
So i posted this question before, and i need some help with syntax please.

How i think of it in pseudo-code is this:

```
var walkingDirection = up;
var walkingDirection1 = down;
var walkingDirection2 = right;
var walkingDirection3 = left;
while (not at T)
    if (next field in walkingDirection is not 1)
        go to next field in walkingDirection
    else if
       (next field in walkingDirection1 is not 1)
        go to next field in walkingDirection1
else if
       (next field in walkingDirection2 is not 1)
        go to next field in walkingDirection2
else if
         (next field in walkingDirection3 is not 1)
        go to next field in walkingDirection3
    end if
end while
```

Please help me with some syntax

```
int myArray[5][10] = { {1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1},
                       {1 1 0 0 0 1 0 T 0 1},
                       {H 0 0 1 1 1 0 1 1 1},
                       {1 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1},
                       {1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1} };
int H = myArray [3][1];
int T = myArray [2][8];

if myArray [a+1][b]==1)
```

Comment: try [A*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/A*_search_algorithm)

Comment: This might serve as a starting point: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14526451/recursive-path-finding-in-matrix?rq=1 Also, you tagged the question with "C", so you should post some C-code, not pseudo code

Comment: "Please help me with some syntax". With which particular aspect of C's syntax are you struggling? Why don't you try converting this to C, compiling it, addressing the output of your compiler and then asking if you have a ***specific*** syntax problem?

Comment: Thanks Andreas!
It is helpful,
Well, i just need somewhere to get started.
I know some basics in C but i can't put it al together..

Comment: @pyetjegoo your pseudocode above doesn't even attempt to work with C syntax really.  Give it a shot, edit your question, and you will probably get some help with the specific C issues.

Comment: Ok Randy, please i'll update it in 4-5 minutes, i was working on it..

Comment: I'm struggling with something like this, i mean, i don't know how to start it.. if i should make a function or something... :/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unfortunately your algorithm won't work for any type of solvable labyrinth.

Taking a closer look at a step by step level at the different stages you are planning to do you'll find be able to verify it even doesn't work for the example labyrinth given.

To see this it is best to play the whole algorithm by example.

```
1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1
1 1 0 0 0 1 0 T 0 1
H 0 0 1 1 1 0 1 1 1
1 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1
1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1
```

Starting at the node `H`:

- first check the `while` condition:

  We are not at node `T` so the loop will be running.
- Inspecting walkingDirection we see there is a `1`, so this branch can't be taken.
- The same holds true for walkingDirection1, so this branch cant't be taken either.

  Instead it's the walkingDirection2 branch that the algorithm will enter making a step to the right.
- walkingDirection3 isn't checked any more as we already visited the walkingDirection2 branch.
- Control flow reaches the end of the while loop.

  Again we have to check the condition: still not at node `T`, so we have to go on.

  ....

Continuing to play the example this way step by step you'll soon find the problem. It's the line marked with `*` in the following picture:

```
1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1
1 1 * 0 0 1 0 T 0 1
H 0 * 1 1 1 0 1 1 1
1 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1
1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1
```

Once your algorithm enters that portion of the dungeon it will continously walk up and down.

- taking the walkDirection branch while it is still possible to walk up.
- taking one step in walkDirection1 which is down one walkDirection is blocked to just turn around in the next run as now walkDirection is walkable again.

### ... so what to do?

While just testing any possible direction is generally not a bad idea - in fact there isn't any other choice but testing and hoping for the best - your algorithm is missing some kind of memory.

To prevent it from running in circles it would have to be able to detect that it already inspected that option or even better "remember" the interesting spots. Those that offer possibilities that have not yet been tested.

While not the most efficient version a very simple idea could be to keep a list of all fields that were already inspected. Keeping a record for every field that was already visited saying something like: the field is at position so-and-so and I came there from field so-and-so you will prevent doing the same error over and over again.

Keeping a second list of all potential candidates that you are able to inspect because you already entered an field next to it remembering something like: i saw field so-and-so when I was standing on field so-and-so and could have taken it that time you should be able to just keep inspecting the most interesting fields.

### Outline

Summing up the ideas given so far the algorithm could be boiled down to two functions:

**next field()**

---

Take one field from the list of the fields that you have seen so far.

If it has already been inspected  discard it as there is no worth in inspecting it again. Keep discarding inspected fields until either:

- your list runs empty: There is no solution to the labyrinth then

  You can just exit the program then.
- you find a field that hasn't been inspected until now.

  In this case **inspect()** it.

.

**inspect field()**

---

Check if you already are at node `T`

- If yes - sing aloud "hooray" as you just managed to escape the dungeon.

  Oh, yes - and you can exit your program here.
- If not

  Enter a new record to your list of inspected fields remembering from where you came.

  Check all neighboring fields if they are reachable and if they already have been inspected.

  - If they are reachable but have not been inspected be sure to add them to the list of interesting fields seen so far remembering from which field you saw them.

    Now continue with the **next_field()**

.

This way the only thing you would have to do once your program starts would be to **inspect ()** the field `H` and wait for the result.

### ... see also

Aiming for higher stakes you might want to take a look into any of the following material:

- http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Breadth-first_search
- http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Depth-first_search
- http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/A*_search_algorithm
- http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dijkstra%27s_algorithm
- http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bellman%E2%80%93Ford_algorithm

Comment: Thanks for yur help..yeah i see the point here.. well, thanks, it's difficult for me to write it on code, i can write the pseudocode the logic behind it, but not the code in C, i mean i can understand if i read it, but me, myself i cannot write it.
Anyways thanks for the help!

Comment: @pyetjegoo if you can't write C at all, I'd like to politely suggest that this sort of problem is probably not something you are ready for yet, at least in the realm of a C program.  This is one of those "learn to walk, before you can run" scenarios.

Comment: @pyetjegoo also, you might want to accept his answer if he helped you